# android studio realm database Realm.init() very slow when debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, realm

Hi there i am using realm database with android studio.

When ever I debug the application the debugger at any realm related methods takes way to long. I mean sometimes 1 minutes.

Is there something i need to do to make this faster in android studio?

When running the application in release mode it's pretty fast.

Comment: do you have native debugger enabled? emulator or real device?